# Getting SQL Server Execution Plan through SMO?

Tags: sql-server

I know I can get the execution plan in Management Studio in XML format using "SET showplan_xml ON".

Is there a way to get the same information through .NET code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SET is just a normal sql command, so if you can send an arbitray string to the server, send "set showplan on".